# Having new environment variable by forcefully applying the new environment variable?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, terminal, environment-variables

When I change environment variable, I just reopen the terminal to have the new environment variable.

When I install the [Rocket Dock](http://rocketdock.com/), and drag & drop the terminal, the environment doesn't seem to change even after I change the variable and click the terminal button.

[image]

Why is this? Is there any way to solve this issue (forcefully applying the new environment variable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because Rocket Dock doesn't know about the new variable. Restart Rocket Dock.